# replace url using preg_replace php

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hi all i know preg_replace can be used for formatting string but
i need help in that concerned area 
my url will be like this

```
www.example.com/en/index.php
```

or

```
www.example.com/fr/index.php
```

what i want is to get

result as

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

i need it in php code so as to set in a session

can anyone please explain how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_replace('/www.example.com\/(.+)\/index.php/i', "www.example.com/index.php?lang=$1", $url);` will do the thing

Comment: why do you use brackets there?

Comment: I thought the OP might need the captured language code, so I added the capturing brackets. Of course I should change the code to reflect how one can access that later.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the delimiters

Comment: hi another prob if i have some thing like this what to do?            www.example.com/en/test1/page.php this is not working for that

Comment: so, basically what you need is anything in form of `example.com/language/something/something/something` to be converted into `example.com/something/something/something`? You can try`preg_replace('/www.example.com\/(.*)\/i', "www.example.com/", $url);`

Comment: add yet another slash before the `/i` and it will

Comment: the result is www.example.com/index.php

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:-

```
$newurl = preg_replace('/\/[a-z][a-z]\//', '/', $url);
```

Note that the search string appears with quotes and forward slashes ('/.../') and that the forward slashes in the URL then have to be escaped (\/).  The language code is then matched with '[a-z][a-z]', but there are several other ways to do this and you may want something more liberal in case there are ever 3 letter codes, or caps.  Equally you may need to do something tighter depending on what other URL schemes might appear.

Comment: sorry here it may also be www.example.com/esp/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I suspect in this instance it would be faster simply to use [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) as follows:

```
$cleanedData = str_replace(array('www.example.com/en/', 'www.example.com/fr/'), '', $sourceData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got a method my thanks to Purpletoucan

```
$newurl = preg_replace('/\/(en|esp|fr)\//', '/', $url);
```

it's working now i think!